# bash script excutes multiple iptables chain

Tags: linux, shell, firewall, iptables, python-iptables

I am using the script below to apply `iptables` by filtering IP from the `whitelist.txt` file.

if I have more than one IP in the list, my `iptables` is showing multiple chains:

```
#!/bin/bash

# allowed ip file location
WHITELIST=/usr/src/firewall/whitelist.txt
#
## Specify where IP Tables is located
#

IPTABLES=/sbin/iptables
IPTABLES_SAVE=/sbin/iptables-save

#
## Save current iptables running configuration in case we want to revert back
##  To restore using our example we would run "/sbin/iptables-restore < /usr/src/iptables.last"
#
$IPTABLES_SAVE > /usr/src/iptables.last
#
## Clear current rules
#
##If current INPUT policy is set to DROP we will be locked out once we flush the rules
## so we must first ensure it is set to ACCEPT.
#
$IPTABLES -P INPUT ACCEPT
echo 'Setting default INPUT policy to ACCEPT'

$IPTABLES -F
echo 'Clearing Tables F'
$IPTABLES -X
echo 'Clearing Tables X'
$IPTABLES -Z
echo 'Clearing Tables Z'

#Always allow localhost.
echo 'Allowing Localhost'
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -j ACCEPT

#
## Whitelist
#

for x in `grep -v ^# $WHITELIST | awk '{print $1}'`; do
echo "Permitting $x..."
# $IPTABLES -A INPUT -s $x -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp -s "$x" --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p udp -m udp -s "$x" --dport 5060 -j ACCEPT
done

# block all other traffice

$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p all -j DROP
#
## Save the rules so they are persistent on reboot.
#
/etc/init.d/iptables save
```

And my iptables -L -n output shows as

```
firewall]# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.125        0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.125        0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:5060
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
ACCEPT     tcp  --  192.168.1.1          0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80
ACCEPT     udp  --  192.168.1.1          0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:5060
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

How to avoid duplicates, whats wrong in that script....

Comment: How does `whitelist.txt` look?

Comment: Perhaps you should put the non-source-address-qualified `$IPTABLES -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` line outside your for-each-source-address loop?

Comment: thanks after entering the no-source-address outside it works perfect.....

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess that your `whitelist.txt` contains two IP's: 192.168.1.125 and 192.168.1.1?!

Then you set three rules per IP, one for SSH, one for HTTP and one for SIP, only you fail to specify `--source`/`-s` for SSH, so naturally for any IP in the whitelist, that rule will be identical to any previous ones.

**TL;DR**: Add a `-s "$x"` to the SSH rule and you should be fine.

Bonus tip: If you want to allow the entire private class C subnet, you can use the syntax `-s 192.168.1.0/24` :-)

Cheers,